# Optimization: Solving the problem $\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{k=1}^{m} a_k \|x-x_k\|^2$

Tags: optimization

I do not know how to start with the following exercise:

> Let $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_m \in \mathbb{R}^n$ be arbitrary and $a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_m$ strictly positive real numbers. Solve the following problem:
>
> $$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^n} \sum_{k=1}^{m} a_k \|x-x_k\|^2$$

I think that this problem corresponds to finding the point hat is geometricallly "closest" to the $x_k$ (under weighted distances) but I do not know how to go further from here.

Could you help me?

Answer (score 2):

Given

$$
f(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{m} a_k \|x-x_k\|^2
$$

the stationary point is determined by solving

$$
f'(x)=0
$$

or

$$
\sum_{k=1}^m a_k (x-x_k) = 0\Rightarrow x\sum_{k=1}^m a_k = \sum_{k=1}^m a_k x_k
$$

and then

$$
x = \frac{\sum_{k=1}^m a_k x_k}{\sum_{k=1}^m a_k}
$$

Comment: The derivation is fine if x is one dimensional.  What about n dimensional (original question)?

Comment: This is a $n$-dimensional solution. Think that $\sum a_k x_k \in R^n$

Comment: What does f'(x)=0 mean when x is n dimensional?

Comment: It is a short notation for $\nabla f(x) = 0$